# How to using google my maps in flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-dependencies, mymaps

I'm building a flight route map that will be intriguing with the device's gps.

I tried in one way to use the google my maps service I created objects there on a satellite map of route names and links. But I did not find a package that supports google my maps.

I tried a second way to do webview but do not see it optimally.
I would love to hear your ideas for execution / someone who knows a package that works with Google my Maps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

plot the gps location data on a map i.e. place map markers on the google map

use google_maps_flutter package for flutter/google maps integration

https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

Comment: I try with this package to add my map from Google but I fail. The file I get from Google is kmz / kml. Do you have another idea?